# How to handle an answer that states that they have the same problem described in the question

Tags: discussion

I received an answer to a question that wasn't an answer, but rather a description of how they too are having the same problem described in the question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16062555/495262

Couple of thoughts:

- They don't really have a question (so I can't suggest they ask a question).
- I get the intent--they are trying to leave information for future users to show them another way they might encounter a similar issue.
- What they want to convey is too big to fit into a comment.

**Question:** How should I handle this?:

- I would hate to downvote it--partially because they are a brand new user, so I'd rather instruct them in some way.
- I'd like to suggest what they *should* do with this information, but I'm not sure what that would be.

Comment: Aaand it's gone.

Comment: If the "answer" supplied any information that would improve your question, consider incorporating that (along with flagging as not an answer).  It's not clear from your question here if that was the case.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, In this specific case I thought it did not.  But that is a good point in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flag it as "not an answer" because that's what it is.

You might also consider adding a comment explaining that if they have the same problem they should try the solutions in other answers (if there are any), and that if they're still having issues after that they should ask their own new question, pointing to your question and explaining how and why the solutions presented there didn't work for them so it isn't just closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You should flag it. It should either be a comment on your question, or a question in it's own right (depending on how much it differs from your question).

You should probably add a comment too just to explain that it isn't an answer and suggest to either ask their question, or favourite yours and maybe the answer to your question solves theirs.

If it's posted as an answer (as it was), then you should flag it as "Not an answer".

Answer (score 1):

You have to read it carefully. Sometimes these answers start "I had the same problem" but end up "and that took care of everything" so they really are answers. Vote them up. Sometimes they include a list of things that didn't help, and as such they would probably make good comments, but the user doesn't have the rep to comment.

Most of the time you should just flag as not an answer. If you're feeling compassionate, leave a comment welcoming the user to SO and explaining that only answers are allowed in the answer area, wait 30 min, and then flag it.

Comment: Good points.  In this specific case there wasn't a solution provided.