# I have the same question, but the answer doesn't work for me. Can't comment, what should I do?

Tags: discussion, comments, questions

Sorry if this has been asked already. I saw some similar questions/answers, but not sure that is the right solution.

I came across a question exactly like the question I have, but the only answer there doesn't work for me. Unfortunately I can't leave a comment, yet I don't want to create another question because it's pretty much exactly the same problem. What should I do? Is it really ok to create another question (linking to original), even though the problem is the same? Is there any other way to bring attention to it? Maybe I should leave a comment as an answer, even though it's not an answer? (That solution relates to this - [How to handle an answer that states that they have the same problem described in the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176932/how-to-handle-an-answer-that-states-that-they-have-the-same-problem-described-in) ). Also this particular question has been asked fairly recently (a week ago), maybe it's best if I wait or ask the question somewhere else? This is confusing.

Would've been nice if I could just add a comment, maybe the rep for leaving comments should be lower? Sorry if that's wrong, just a suggestion.

Comment: Does the answer look like it worked for the OP?

Comment: it's not selected as an answer and op didn't say anything about it. it has one vote up.

Comment: Hmm, I wrote an answer [here about this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209121/220332), this question may be a duplicate of that (although I prefer the way this one is phrased). If the question has any issues you can edit it to bring it back to peoples attention

Comment: I quite liked a couple of your posts so now you're 3 rep from commenting. Make a couple of good edits and you're there

Answer (score 9):

> Is it really ok to create another question (linking to original), even though the problem is the same?

No, that's not ok. The duplicate will get closed.

> Maybe I should leave a comment as an answer, even though it's not an answer?

Please don't do that either. Answers that are not answers will be deleted.

> Would've been nice if I could just add a comment, maybe the rep for leaving comments should be lower?

It's only 50, which is pretty low. You have 32 reputation on Stack Overflow already, so you're almost there. You can get that with one or two helpful answers or just nine helpful edit suggestions.

> Is there any other way to bring attention to it?

Yes, you could share it on Twitter, Facebook, your personal blog, within your company... anywhere that you know anyone who might be able to help answer the question.  If you can add relevant information to the question, you can also edit it to bring it back to the top of the active list on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. as far as rep though I've been here actively for at least half a year to get to 32 rep. In my case I'm close I guess, but in more newb cases this may not be a solution. btw I'm not smart enough to answer questions yet (unless by accident it's something I've done), which should be true for most newbs.

Comment: @Chemist It gets harder and harder to gain reputation on SO, but 50 is still a fairly low hurdle that you should be able to get over. (You already have, as of a few minutes ago.) I've found that you really have to narrow your focus to answering questions in tags that you're very familiar with. Set up favorites and browse unanswered questions in tags for technologies that you work with every day. Hope that helps.

Comment: I just had another thought - it would also be helpful if one could send a message to OP, who can then make an action to either comment or choose solution.