# What to do if I didn't get the answer in already answered question

Tags: discussion, questions

I was searching something then I find that the question is already asked and answered, but the cause of the problem was bit different, and so the answer.

So I decided to post the question again, but it will mark as duplicate.
So what to do in that case, should I edit that question according to me, or should I post my question as an **answer** in that question, as creating an comment, but it will not bump the question [again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped)

Comment: Once you have enough reputation, you can post a bounty.

Comment: See also [I have the same question, but the answer doesn't work for me.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226608/i-have-the-same-question-but-the-answer-doesnt-work-for-me-cant-comment-wha)

Comment: And what if I don't have enough reputation?

Comment: That's funny cuz the answer here didn't work for me either...

Comment: Try applying this advice in advance http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not/194479#194479 to prevent the marking as duplicate - if you're sure it really isn't a duplicate, explain why.

Answer (score 4):

> So I decided to post the question again, but it will mark as duplicate.

Then either the answer is deemed the same, although the question is a little different, or you didn't make it clear enough the question is different and in what way.

We appreciate it if you do your part in finding help, so finding a related duplicate helps us a lot. Just put something like this in your question:

> I have found [question X] that (partially) answers my question. However, my question is a little different because ... and the answer didn't help because of that.
>
> ... resume your question with full explanation and code as you normally would

If the question just deviates a little, because a new framework version came and there are slight coding issues, you could raise a bounty to attract new answers. Make sure to explain in your bounty reason that you actually expect that kind of answers.

Comment: and in that case I will not mark as duplicate right?

Comment: Usually close-voters will take a closer look than *oh, this is very similar > vote to close*. Still, you should know that subject-matter-experts have a deeper knowledge than you, so they still may think it is a duplicate, it is not a guarantee that your question won't be closed.

Comment: Typically it takes a little more to not be a duplicate other then a framework version difference, if after you make that clear and it's still closed, you might have to accept the people who know he answer to your question is saying it's a duplicate it might actually be a duplicate

Comment: Yeah. Bad example @ram. You are right: let the experts decide.